# Unable to make images responsive

Tags: twig, craftcms

```
width="{{ asset.getWidth('img') }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight('img') }}" , `This classes don't work as intended they just do nothing.`
```

I am creating a blog and when i make a entry, my images just occupy the whole screen. They also don't shorten when responsive.

```
{% set myAssetQuery = craft.assets() %}
  {% set images = myAssetQuery.all() %}
  <ul>
      {% for image in images %}
          <li><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('img') }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth('img') }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight('img') }}"></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('secscrpt') %}
  {% for block in entry.matriz %}
  {{ block.body }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You would need more than just a default `image`-tag to make images responsive. You could use javascript, css mediaquaries or the `srcset` of the `img`-tag

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain images to their containers by doing something like `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`.

To fully support responsive images you likely want to setup a system of transforms that you can use. These transforms are setup in Settings > Assets > Image Transforms.

Assuming you make transforms name small, medium, large, these would be used in your templates like this:

```
{% set images = myAssetQuery.all() %}
<ul>
    {% for image in images %}
        <li>
            <picture>
                <source srcset="{{ image.getUrl('large') }}" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
                <source srcset="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" media="(min-width: 900px)">
                <source srcset="{{ image.getUrl('small') }}" media="(min-width: 500px)">
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
            </picture>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can also use the srcset option on the img tag like so:

```
{% set images = myAssetQuery.all() %}
<ul>
    {% for image in images %}
        <li>
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"
              srcset="{{ image.getUrl('large') }} {{ image.getWidth('large') }}w,
                      {{ image.getUrl('medium') }} {{ image.getWidth('medium') }}w,
                      {{ image.getUrl('small') }} {{ image.getWidth('small') }}w"
               sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 1200px,
                      (max-width: 900px) 900px,
                      500px">
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```